# Unable to understand why Method not displaying returned string using JAVA Interface

Tags: java, string

Programming novice.  Working on an assignment with interfaces.  I have a display main app that calls a CountUtil class method called count which uses Countable as an argument (CountUtil.count(a, count); [LINE 21] right after i declare a as an Alligator object).  Alligator implements the Countable interface.

The CountUtil.count method should reset a count variable using the Alligator resetCount() method, print out the return value of the getCountString() method at least 4 in the while loop, and increment the count.

I can not get the getCountString() method to display the while loop returned string, and I can not fugure out why.  Any feedback would be helpful.  Thanks.

```
public class DisplayableTestApp {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    BellHeading.getHeading("Assignment 8 - Processing Interfaces");
    countAlligators();
    //countSheep();
    //countMyself;
    //endItAll;
}

public static void countAlligators() {
    int count = 4;
    System.out.printf("  Counting alligators... I see %d\n", count);
    Alligator a = new Alligator();
    CountUtil.count(a, count);
}

//public static void countSheep() {
  //  System.out.printf("  Counting sheep... I see ");
//}
}
```

Alligator Class

```
public class Alligator implements Countable {
private int count; //declaring integer

public Alligator (){ //constructor
    count = 1; //initializing variable
}    

@Override     //implementation of Countable interface
public void incrementCount() {
    count++;
}

@Override     //implementation of Countable interface
public void resetCount() {
    count = 1;
}

@Override     //implementation of Countable interface
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override     //implementation of Countable interface
public String getCountString() {
    return String.format("  %d alligator\n",count);
}
}
```

CountUtil Class

```
public class CountUtil {

public static void count(Countable c, int maxCount) {
    c.resetCount();
    while (c.getCount() <= maxCount){
        c.getCountString();
        c.incrementCount();
    } //end while loop
} //end count method
} //end CountUtil class
```

Countable Interface

```
public interface Countable {
void incrementCount();
void resetCount();
int getCount();
String getCountString();
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(c.getCountString());`

Comment: You can't figure out why nothing is getting printed when you don't call a print method. For reals?

Comment: String.format("  %d alligator\n",count); - This would just format the string. To get this printed on the console, you need to explicitly call print method as System.out.println(c.getCountString());

Comment: Stupid mistake.  Now that you point it out I can see it clearly.  Still trying to retain how void methods and type methods that return a value present data.  Noob.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You haven't print the count anywhere. Change your `CountUtil` class as follows

```
public class CountUtil {
    public static void count(Countable c, int maxCount) {
        c.resetCount();
        while (c.getCount() <= maxCount) {
            System.out.println(c.getCountString());  // Printing...
            c.incrementCount();
        } // end while loop
    } // end count method
} // end CountUtil class
```